# jumpt to another controller from inside the controller symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2.8.
I would like to jump to the controller from another controller.How is it possible?

This is my source code below

DefaultController.php

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
    public function myFirstAction(){
    // do something
    if ($a = 1){
       $this->mySecondAction() //  error
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:myFirst.html.twig',array());
    }
}

public function mySecondAction(){
     //do something
        return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:mySecond.html.twig',array());
}
```

$this->mySecondAction() shows error like

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\MemberBundle\Controller\DefaultController::secondAction() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given, called in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Symfony actions are passed a Request instance. You should be able to fix this error by adding the corresponding parameter to both action functions and passing it in your call to mySecondAction()

Also, don't forget that actions must return a Response, you're not returning the result of mySecondAction() in your code.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
    public function myFirstAction(Request $request){
    // do something
    if ($a = 1){
       return $this->mySecondAction($request) //  Note the return I added here
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:myFirst.html.twig',array());
    }
}

public function mySecondAction(Request $request){
     //do something
        return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:mySecond.html.twig',array());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jumpt to **another** controller, you could define it as a service, however if you have the functions in the same controller you could use @AmericanUmlaut answer.

Define the controller as a service and get the function 'mySecondAction()' and using the service previously defined, for example:

Then you can define it as a service as follows:
services.yml file

```
services:
app.mySecondAction:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Controller:

```
  public function myFirstAction() {
    // do something      
    if ($a = 1) {
        //using the service previously defined
        $service = $this->get('app.mySecondAction');
        return $service->mySecondAction();           
    } else {
        return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:myFirst.html.twig', array());
    }
 }

public function mySecondAction(){
    //do something
    return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:mySecond.html.twig',array());
}
```

Comment: In my case @AmericanUmlaut way is enough, however your answer is good for further study or someone need this, thank you very much.